# How to generate gem package for rubygems manually?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to generate the gem package for [rubygems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems) based on the master branch, which is later than the last release. Anyone know how to do it?

I want to get the file `rubygems-update-xxx.gem` with master branch version.

Cheers

Comment: `git clone NAME && gem build NAME.gemspec`

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for `rubygems`

Comment: Sure it works. You can not upload it to rubygems unless you are the owner, which is perfectly reasonable. And your question was “I want to get the file rubygems-update-xxx.gem with master branch version” which says nothing about rubygems at all. It would be great if you would try to put some effort in stating questions instead of abusing correct answers.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thanks. I think you are misunderstanding my question. I was asking about `rubygems` itself, which you can check the version by `gem -v`, not point to any gems like `rake`, `sidekiq`. etc.

Comment: Uh. Do you want to build `rubygems`` gem itself locally? Besides I hardly can imagine the reason to do that, I doubt it is possible at all.

Comment: @mudasobwa There is a bug in the 2.7.1 and a fix after that version, that's the reason I want to build it locally to verify. Now the 2.7.2 is released and the bug has been fixed.

Comment: In such a case for wide-used gems people usually _downgrade locally_, not rebuild the internet :)

Comment: @mudasobwa Someone did it before the 2.7.2 release by using the local build `rubygems`, so I would like to know how he got it. https://vimeo.com/241787686